# Responsive Dropdown Menus not opening properly in two column view

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Basically I am working on filters to filter table contents. I have four filters to deal with. They are responsive as I am using Bootstrap. But when I resize my browser window to 75% width, then two column view jump in. In two column view all the dropdowns are working fine except the first one(Products). When I open the first one and close all other dropdowns, all the dropdowns are shifting to right of filter 1. I want the product dropdown to behave like audience dropdown.[This is the product dropdown, I want it to open like audience dropdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/phe8f.png).............[This is the audience dropdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SZaWp.png)

```js
function showFilter(filter) {
    var x = document.getElementById(filter.parentNode.childNodes[3].id);
    if (x.style.display === 'none') {
        x.style.display = 'block';
    } else {
        x.style.display = 'none';
    }
 }
```

```css
.filter-button {
 width: 100%;
 background-color: #005387;
 -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
 -moz-border-radius: 0px;
 border-radius: 0px;
 vertical-align: bottom;
 }
 
 .filter-menu {
 width: 100%;
 height: 110px;
 overflow: auto;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0);
 -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0);
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0);
 -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
 -moz-border-radius: 0px;
 border-radius: 0px;
 padding:10px;
 border: 1px solid #ddd;
 }
 
 /* attaches the filter toggles to the top of the filter boxes */
 #product-filters, #language-filters, #medium-filters {
 vertical-align: top;
 }
 
 /* filter menu items */
 .filter-menu input {
 vertical-align: top;
 }
  
 .filter-label {
 font-weight: normal !important;
 margin-left: 10px;
 margin-bottom:7px;
 }
 
 .filter-label:before {
 font-weight: normal !important;
 }
 
 .filter-box {
padding-left:500px !important;
 }
 
 .filter-menu li {
 list-style-type: none;
 }

 .filter-parent {
 margin:0;
 }
```

```html
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
      <!-- Products Filter Menu -->
      
                        <div class = "filter-parent col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col" id = "product-filters">
      <button class="btn btn-primary filter-button" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" onclick="showFilter(this)">Products
      <span class="caret caret-reversed"></span></button>
      <ul class="filter-menu" id="productFilters">
      <!--Filters load dynamically here-->
      </ul>
      </div>
                        
      
      <!-- Roles Filter Menu -->
      
      <div class = "filter-parent col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col" id = "role-filters">
      <button class="btn btn-primary filter-button" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown"  onclick="showFilter(this)">Audiences
      <span class="caret caret-reversed"></span></button>
      <ul class="filter-menu" id="roleFilters">
      <!--Filters load dynamically here-->
      </ul>
      </div>
      
      <!-- Delivery Methods Filter Menu -->
      <div class = "filter-parent col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col" id = "medium-filters">
      <button class="btn btn-primary filter-button" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown"  onclick="showFilter(this)">Delivery Methods
      <span class="caret caret-reversed"></span></button>
      <ul class="filter-menu" id="mediumFilters">
      <!--Filters load dynamically here-->
      </ul>
      </div>
      
      <!-- Languages Filter Menu -->
      <div class = "filter-parent col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col" id = "language-filters">
      <button class="btn btn-primary filter-button" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown"  onclick="showFilter(this)">Languages
      <span class="caret caret-reversed"></span></button>
      <ul class="filter-menu" id="languageFilters">
      <!--Filters load dynamically here-->
      </ul>
      </div>
      </div> <!--end of row div-->
     </div> <!-- end of filter container div -->
  </body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I find the solution to my problem...

```
@media (max-width: 991px) {
    #medium-filters {
      clear: left;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because the divs are floating.

A quick solution would be to clear the third div

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    #mediumFilters {
      clear: left;
    }
}
```